# Liquid layout with liquid left + fixed right column

Tags: jquery, html, css

The question is pretty self explanatory. All these div elements are 100% in height I need the left div to flex, but not have it set to overflow:hidden so that I can make it's children elements be elastic as well. Inside the left div is an Image slider which is responsive and I'm trying to make it responsive. can someone help me with my css for this please thanks in advance.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">
         Liquid layout
    </div>
    <div id="right">
         Fixed width 450px
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If div elements are **100% of window height** then your HTML+CSS markup is reduced to:

```html
<div id="left">Liquid layout</div>
<div id="right">Fixed width 450px</div>
```

```css
html   { height: 100%; }
body   { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#left  { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 450px; }
#right { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 450px; }
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/X4SFE/2/)

---

If div elements are **equal height** then here is an "old school" approach that (i) Preserves source order (ii) Uses floats (iii) Produces equal height faux columns (iv) Requires one clearing div

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">Liquid layout</div>
    <div id="right">Fixed width 450px</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent { border-right: 450px solid orange /* right bg */; background-color: yellow /* left bg */; }
#left   { float: left;  width: 100%; }
#right  { float: right; width: 450px; margin-right: -450px; }
.clear  { clear: both; }
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/X4SFE/1/)

Comment: Can I give you a hug? You seriously just made my week.

Answer (score 1):

use `table-cell` for your purpose :)

**EDIT after Hashem Qolami answer**, since you have tagged question in `css3` category, let me be clear that `display:table` is supported IE8 and onwards....and is useful if you don't wanna mess around with `clear`ing the divs!!

<kbd>[**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JsW3N/1/)</kbd>

```
 html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#parent {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    word-break:break-all;
}
#left {
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#right {
    width:450px;
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this layout by setting a `float` property to one `div` and using `margin` for the other one:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="right">
         Fixed width 450px
    </div>
    <div id="left">
         Liquid layout
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
}

#left {
  margin-right: 450px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6LGEr/)**

There's no need to use `table` displayed elements. In fact, I really recommend to avoid using that for layout purposes.

**Note:** Using `table` display types, may change behavior of web browser while rendering the page (browsers may consider the entire page as a table).

According to **[W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)**:

> **table, inline-table, table-row-group, table-column,
>   table-column-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row,
>   table-cell, and table-caption**
>
> These values cause an element to **behave
>   like a [table](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html)** element (subject to restrictions described in the chapter
>   on tables).

Comment: you could have pointed out directly to my answer mate, i generally don't criticize others answer....mind answering why `display:table` is a bad idea, considering you have to `clear` the float and consider the associated layouts too in it???...and since question is tagged `css3`, i don't think old-browser support is an issue!!

Comment: You have changed the order of columns. May or may not be acceptable.

Comment: How are HTML table elements (table,tr,td,th,etc) and CSS values of the `display` property related except former elements have these values as default rendering? Is your link "Further reading on SO" related to the CSS `display` value? The first answer with ~498 votes is unrelated, please be more precise if other answers are related)

Comment: @hashem : what you have quoted as an SO answer is for `html table` not `css table`...both are totally different.....with so much of reputation that u have, you should have been able to understand the difference rather than misleading the OP, just to prove your point!!!

Comment: @HashemQolami : you made `display:table` look so bad...but its not that bad, atleast i never faced a problem with that, even on IE8 !!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I mentioned `browsers may..`, But according to spec, I can't recommend someone to use `table` element or `table` displayed elements for layout purposes. But it's the best choice for tabular data.

Comment: Just 1 small, **objective** point of difference between table layout and floated layout. When rendering below 450px, the float way shows the right margin of the div. The table way shows the left margin.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to go with the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) approach than here you go...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KPSem/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fluid"></div>
    <div class="fixed"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, .wrap, .wrap > div {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

.fluid {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    flex: 1;
}

.fixed {
    background: #aaa;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: one poster already objected `display:table` given by me and then vanished...and now you come with another so called non-consistent browser solution, that makes 2 of us..+1 though!! :)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5HSD7/)

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#left, #right {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#parent{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}   

#left {
   width: calc(100% - 450px);;
   background-color: teal; 
}
#right {    
    width: 450px;
    background-color: olive; 
}
```