# Two divs side by side set to display: table-cell, but text in the second column is dropping down

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, css-tables

I have a layout where I have a wrapper div and two child divs.

The parent div is set to `display: table` and the child divs are set to `display: table-cell`.

I have set the first `table-cell` div to `width: 35%`.

It works fine in Chrome, but when it displays in IE10 (or below), the text appears below the image, or appears with a massive amount of padding.

**Here's the HTML of the tables:**

```
<!-- Display: table div -->
<div class="about_us_row_content_wrapper boxsizing">
                            <!-- Table cell 1 with width 35% -->
                <div class="about_us_column about_us_image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $link_path . 'images/aboutus/all_devices.png'; ?>" alt="Works on all devices, such as tablets, mobiles and desktops" />
                </div>
                            <!-- Table cell 2 with assumed auto width, but text is dropping down-->
                <div class="about_us_column">
                    <h3 class="opensans_thin about_us_section_header">Polls Everywhere, No compromises</h3>
                    <p class="about_us_section_paragraph">We worked hard so that you can make and take polls anywhere, anytime - no matter which device you're using.</p>
                    <p class="about_us_section_paragraph">Our fully featured poll maker works perfectly on phones, tablets and traditional desktops.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Here's the key pieces of CSS:**

```
div.about_us_row_content_wrapper { display: table; max-width: 990px; text-align: left; }
.boxsizing { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
div.about_us_row_content_wrapper img { vertical-align: top; } 
div.about_us_column { display: table-cell; }
div.about_us_image { margin-left: 50px; width: 35%; }
h3.about_us_section_header { margin: 0 0 24px 0; vertical-align: top; font-size: 1.5em; }
p.about_us_section_paragraph { vertical-align: top; }
```

I have tried adding `vertical-align: top;` to all of the text inside the cell, but this doesn't work.

I have also tried adding `width: 50%` to both of the cells to see if this gives the text enough room to rise upwards, but it doesn't.

The table-cell elements don't have a `min-height` on them either, or padding, so I'm not sure where it's getting it from.

The code is live [Here](http://makeapoll.net/about-us)

**Here is it working fine in Chrome:**
[image: fine in chrome]

**Here is it not working as expected in IE10:**
[image: IE10]

Comment: Where is @NoobEditor, here is `display: table`.. :) @Hashem Qolami

Comment: I'm afraid you've lot me there with that comment :(

Comment: In this latest question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378240/liquid-left-div-right-div-fixed-for-liquid-layout/21379082#21379082.... there was a lot of argument on using `display: table`

Comment: I see, well I don't really want to use `floats`.  I've used `display: table` for it's fluid properties.  I also found it was easy to align things using it too, but in this case it's not working... it's bizarre.  Any ideas?  Please vote up if you think it's a worthy question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give vertical align to top :- apply this to all ur right columns

```
.about_us_column{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Yes this has worked, thank you!  I'm not sure why though, I thought that the table properties should sets the alignment anyway?

Comment: It is similar to making a `td` text `vertical-align: top`

Comment: But the table cell should push up automatically.  I have never set vertical-alignment on an actual cell before.  It usually does this automatically?

Comment: But super intelligent browser IE misses it.. :)